# How to properly filter columns after applying aggregate function

Tags: sqlite, syntax

I find that I need to apply an aggregate a lot, but I don't want to show the aggregated value as well. So the best way to do this was to just nest the query to filter it out (like below) but there has to be a better way, how?

```
select state
from(
    select state, max(cnt)
    from (
        select state, count(*) as cnt
        from customer
        group by state) as t
) as r;
```

Here I just want to show `state` without the max value.

Comment: You want the state with the max count? What is there are two (or more) with the same max count?

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ it will take one of them I guess? It doesn't matter.

Comment: I said it (the result) doesn't matter, I guessed the behavior. @ypercubeᵀᴹ

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can achieve this result without so many subqueries:

```
Select State
  From Customer
  Group By State
  Order By Count(*) Desc
  Limit 1;
```

Comment: Nice to know it's possible to limit the query.